# What is the minimum secure length for gpg -c file.txt?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, gnupg

I want to use `gpg -c` with a user-generated password that I can easily remember. Are 16 characters enough? for example would a password similar to "`I own 32 houses.`" be bruteforcable?

Answer (score 1):

## Misconceptions

> Is 16 characters enough? for example would a password similar to "I own 32 houses." be bruteforcable?

"I own 32 houses." should not be considered a 16 character password.  A modern cracker would use a dictionary attack to break that one.  A 16 character password would be pretty strong 26^16 = 4.3608743e+22 possible combinations, but you would need to have random characters. Assuming a dictionary of 20k words (the common english speaker's vocab) and 33 special characters. The password you supplied is really 20,000 x 20,000 x 99 x 20,000 = 7.92e+14 possible combinations.

## Answer

I'd recommend 16 characters for this scenario, but you need to use a high entropy password generator.

You can use [this](https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm) website to check lengths of passwords and how long they would take to crack for offline attacks, but remember you need a randomly generated password for this tool to work.

Comment: it's not 20k * 20k * 99 * 20k. its (any common word + any punctuation + any number 0-9999)^4. how many combination is an acceptable number?

Comment: the website you linked seems to suggest 1e23 is around the minimum acceptable combinations?

Comment: the `Massive Cracking Array Scenario` is for nation state actors trying to crack your file, so if you are worried about that, then go for 17 random chars.